# undefined method each_with_index activerecord-import

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in Rails for stock price history and I'd like to mass import that data from yahoo finance api into my model.

This is what I have:

```
columns = [:date,:open,:high,:low,:close,:volume,:adjusted_close,:asset_symbol]
values = ['2013-03-22',1,2,3,4,5,6,'YHOO']

AssetHistory.import columns,values
```

Which results in an error saying: `undefined method each_with_index for '2013-03-22':String from .../activerecord-import/import.rb`

Note that the date in my values array is actually of type date in my model. (Is that the issue?)

I am using Activerecord-import 0.3.1 and Rails 3.2. I am also using Postgresql if that matters.

My Asset History model with annotation:

```
# Table name: asset_histories
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  date           :date
#  open           :float
#  high           :float
#  low            :float
#  close          :float
#  volume         :integer
#  adjusted_close :float
#  asset_symbol   :string(255)
#  asset_id       :integer
#

class AssetHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :adjusted_close, :close, :date, :high, :low, :open, :volume, :asset_id, :asset_symbol
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assets
  validates_uniqueness_of :asset_symbol, scope: [:date]
end
```

Any reason what this issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While importing the objects into model, we should call the method as below.

```
Model.import <array_of_cols>, <array_of_values>
```

For example:

```
Sample.import [:field1, :field2], [["value-a1", "value-a2"], ["value-b1", "value-b2"]]
```

The above example will create two records of the **Sample** model.

So in your case, please provide like this.

```
AssetHistory.import columns, [values]
```

Hope this will work.